# PHP - Slowloris shell

Tags: php

How would I get my script to send out a loop of Post data to the Apache server?

I have tried creating one and it does not loop.

This is done on education base.

It would need to have Host + Time, the loop depends on the time inputted.

Comment: You should be more specific. Maybe post some of your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look on curl_multi_exec

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: How would curl relate to this? I will have to make the script so that people can enter host + time into the PHP shell.

Comment: `php+post=curl` almost always. As I said in the comment to your question. Be more specific and add some code.